# Extend footer wrap to width of page

Tags: html, css, shtml

I've made a footer wrap outside the content wrap (which everything else is in).  I would like to make the footer wrap extend to fill the width of the page and I would like it to be fixed on the bottom.  Here's the code:

## footerWrap {

```
background-color:#000;
width: auto;
```

}

## footer {

```
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
width:965px;
height:150px;
background-color:#000;
border:#000 inset medium;
```

}

The website is item9andthemadhatters.com  please let me know if you need any other code or info.  Thanks!!

update:

html {
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: calibri;
    background-image:url(images/item9HeaderSideFiller.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

## wrap {

```
width: 965px;
margin:auto auto;
min-height:462px;
max-height:4000
```

px;

## footerWrap {

```
background-color:#000;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%
```

}

## footer {

```
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
width:965px;
height:150px;
background-color:#000;
```

}

}

Comment: #footerWrap {
 background-color:#000;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%
 
}

#footer {
 margin: auto;
 text-align:center;
 width:965px;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#000;
}

Comment: html {
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body{
 margin: -1px 0 0 0;
 background-color:#FFF;
 font-family: calibri;
 background-image:url(images/item9HeaderSideFiller.gif);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}



#wrap {
 width: 965px;
 margin:auto auto;
 min-height:462px;
 max-height:4000px;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill the page

```
width:100%
```

To stay at the bottom of the page a solution could be

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

notice that in both body and html you have to set

```
padding:0
height:100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This didn't work.  I'll post more code.

Comment: @hawkeye126 , I checked your website. The footer is inside the wrap! You must place it as direct child of the body element

Comment: Thanks for the help.  As far as I can tell I have the footer wrap div after the wrap div.  If it wasn't I just uploaded the newer code again.  How do I place it as a direct child of the body element? Thanks again for your help, I think it's close.

Answer (score 0):

Try `width:100%` in footerWrap. Also, what do you mean by fixed on the bottom? Do you mean the footer should always be at the bottom of the screen, even when scrolling? Or do you mean it should always be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I mean that should always be at the bottom so there is no whitespace under it, between it and the browser window.  I tried changing the width to 100% and it didn't.  I'll edit my question and post more code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: hold the phones!  It works now.  THanks a bunch for the help everyone!